# How to optimize this nested SQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-optimization

Here is the database schema:

[redacted]

I'll describe what I'm doing with the query below:

**Innermost query**: Select all the `saleId`s satisfying the `WHERE` conditions

**Middle query**: Select all the `productId`s that were a part of the `saleId`

**Outermost query**: `SUM` the `products.cost` and select the `vendors.name`.

And here is the SQL query I came up with:

```
SELECT vendors.name AS Company
, SUM(products.cost) AS Revenue
FROM
    products
    INNER JOIN sold_products
        ON (products.productId = sold_products.productId)
    INNER JOIN vendors
    ON (products.vendorId = vendors.vendorId)
            WHERE sold_products.productId IN (
                    SELECT sold_products.productId
                    FROM
                        sold_products
                    WHERE sold_products.saleId IN (
                            SELECT sales.saleId     
                            FROM
                                markets
                                INNER JOIN vendors
                                ON (markets.vendorId = vendors.vendorId)
                                INNER JOIN sales_campaign
                                ON (sales_campaign.marketId = markets.marketId)
                                INNER JOIN packet_headers
                                ON (sales_campaign.packetHeaderId = packet_headers.packetHeaderId)
                                INNER JOIN packet_details
                                ON (packet_details.packetHeaderId = packet_headers.packetHeaderId)
                                INNER JOIN sales
                                ON (sales.packetDetailsId = packet_details.packetDetailsId)
                            WHERE vendors.customerId=60
                            )
                    )
GROUP BY Company
ORDER BY Revenue DESC;
```

Any help in optimizing this?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` tell you? What have you tried?

Comment: @Bohemian: `EXPLAIN` shows me a detailed table, but I'm afraid I don't understand what it means..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just using inner joins you normally simplify the query to smth like this:

```
SELECT  ve.name     AS Company
,       SUM(pr.cost) AS Revenue
FROM    products        pr
,       sold_products   sp
,       vendors         ve
,       markets         ma
,       sales_campaign  sc
,       packet_headers  ph
,       packet_details  pd
,       sales           sa
Where pr.productId = sp.productId
And   pr.vendorId  = ve.vendorId
And   ve.vendorId  = ma.vendorId
And   sc.marketId = ma.marketId
And   sc.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId
And   pd.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId)
And   sa.packetDetailsId = pd.packetDetailsId
And   ve.customerId = 60
GROUP BY ve.Company
ORDER BY pr.Revenue DESC;
```

Please try if this works and if it is faster and let me know.

Comment: Heiz Matchinger: This is exactly what I was doing before, but the result was a completely wrong. This query would return `SUM(products.cost)` of ALL the products, whether they are sold or not..

Comment: have you checked if it is really ALL products or if its just SUMs a  product multiple times?! with the join to sold_products it can not SUM all products! Look at your query without the SUM => what is the result?

Comment: Yes it really is a SUM of ALL the products by that Vendor; not the SUM of just the ones that were sold..

Comment: Try to simplify for finding the bug:
SELECT  ve.name     AS Company
,       SUM(pr.cost) AS Revenue
FROM    products        pr
,       sold_products   sp
,       vendors         ve
Where pr.productId = sp.productId
And   pr.vendorId  = ve.vendorId
And   ve.customerId = 60
GROUP BY ve.Company
ORDER BY pr.Revenue DESC;

Comment: Wow that works perfectly! And instantaneously too!! Thanks :)

Comment: Is this type of `WHERE` a good replacement for `INNER JOINS` that I was using?